# Encryption with RSA algorithm(SIZE of input)

Tags: java

I need to encrypt a file (4kb), but when I try to encrypt it using RSA it is showing the error:

> The size must not be greater than 256 bytes.

Is there any chance to encrypt the data of large size using RSA algorithm??

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [encrypting and decryption large file using rsa in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512300/encrypting-and-decryption-large-file-using-rsa-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you need to encrypt every 256 bytes seperately and group them in an array.

In Java you can do this:

```
private List<byte[]> encryptFile(String filename) throws IOException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    byte[] bytesFromFile = new byte[256];
    List<byte[]> listToReturn = new ArrayList();
    FileInputStream fis = new  FileInputStream(new File(filename));
    while(fis.read(bytesFromFile) > 0) {
        // insert cipher of your choice
        listToReturn.add(Cipher.getInstance("").doFinal(bytesFromFile));
    }
    return listToReturn;
}
```